# Coloring entire row after inserting row code ran

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that inserts row after certain changes in numbers. How do I insert into the code to color the inserted rows?

```
  Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    'Update 20140716
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to add approaches you've already tried?

Comment: I am very new to VBA but I tried adding Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

Comment: Note that you should remove `On Error Resume Next` this hides **all** error messages untiil `End Sub` but the errors still occur you just cannot see their messages. So if errors occur you cannot fix them because you cannot see them. This is a very bad approach. You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Answer (score 1):

Try below. It is set to blue but you can use any color.

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    'Update 20140716
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert

        'add color
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That gets me about half way to my goal lol I would like it to color the whole row that was inserted not just the cell. I tried replacing Cell with Rows and it doesn't colorize it than....Update..It worked thank you!

Comment: Yes, I corrected the code to color .EntireRow instead of just one cell. Please approve the answer, if it is correct. Thanks :)